# what is the value of a so that the set {(1,-1,0),(a,0,-1),(1,2,3)} is linear dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the value of a so that the set {(1,-1,0),(a,0,-1),(1,2,3)} is linear dependent?

ok so I'm guessing that in order to solve this maybe you have to take the determinant of this = 0 and solve for a?

I can't figure out how to reduce it in such a way that you can get a row of (a,0,0) to = k, which would make it linear dependent if I'm correct

Answer (score 1):

Vector $(a,0,-1)$ is linear dependent of vectors $(1,-1,0),(1,2,3)$ if exists real numbers $x,y\neq0$ such that
$$(a,0,-1)=x\cdot(1,-1,0)+y\cdot(1,2,3)=$$
$$=(x,-x,0)+(y,2y,3y)=(x+y,-x+2y,3y)$$
from above you get the system
$$x+y=a$$
$$-x+2y=0$$
$$3y=-1$$ 
solving the system we get that
$x=-2/3,y=-1/3,a=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct, if we want the three vectors to be linearly dependent we require:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1 & a & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & 3\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Expanding the determinant we get:

$$3+3a=0 \implies 3a=-3\implies a=-1$$

And we thus find that: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ are linearly dependent (i.e. the matrix has a rank of $2$).